# Folder Permissions denied with Nitro

Tags: permissions, nitro

I’m getting this error when accessing/writing images. It’s only just come along suddenly after one or a couple of updates.

> League\Flysystem\Exception
>
> Impossible to create the root directory
> "/Users/username/Sites/project-name/craft/web/images/folder". mkdir():
> Permission denied

- Running Nitro with Multipass 1.5
- Multipassd has all Full Disk Access (but had to add this manually from Application Services)
- Craft CMS 3.5.16
- MacOS Catalina 10.15.7
- Composer version 2.0.8
- Unable to change file permissions in Finder/Transmit etc
- Not new installs
- Unable to load an image through CP. Same message as above

Nitro running other simpler site fine, so no problems there.

At a loss, any site running locally that needs images will fail to load, but /admin runs all fine.

Thanks :)

Comment: Does ``nitro apply && nitro restart`` do any for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be because you are setting your Settings → Assets → your volume **File System Path** to an absolute location **outside** the VM.

Create an [alias](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/#aliases) (or *hard-set* `webroot`) using:

```
'aliases' => [
    'webroot' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/web'
],
```

In your `config/general.php` (changing `web` if you have a different public root).

With this in place, change the **File System Path** of your volume to `@webroot/your/path` which should solve you issue.

Comment: Cheers Oli, this solved the issue I was having.